# How to get Name of knockout observable?

Tags: knockout.js, typescript, observable

In my ViewModel (typescript )
I have a observable as

public testObservable: KnockoutObservable = ko.observable();

How can I get 'name' of this observable ?

in this case result (name of observable) is 'testObservable'

Comment: Explain why and where do you need the name of the observable? Do you need the name just for this observable or all observables that you declare? Maybe you are just trying to do something that is possible to do in a different way.

Comment: I need name of some of the observables in my viewmodel, which I want to use as a key further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, your observable would be the property of a ViewModel, something like this:

```
var view_model = {
    testObservable: ko.observable()
}
```

You can get the name by iterating through the object:

```
var name = '';

for (var prop in view_model) {
    if (view_model.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        name = prop;
    }
}
```

This will work if it is the only property of your ViewModel.